# PHP from JSON array

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "cache": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "unique_id": "914239",
      "description": "New Zealand 370/10 &amp;  335/10  v Australia 70/1 &amp;  505/10 *",
      "title": "New Zealand 370/10 &amp;  335/10  v Australia 70/1 &amp;  505/10 *"
    },
    {
      "unique_id": "973833",
      "description": "Helmand Province Under-17s 135/10 * v Khost Province Under-17s 286/9 ",
      "title": "Helmand Province Under-17s 135/10 * v Khost Province Under-17s 286/9 "
    },
    {
      "unique_id": "935949",
      "description": "Mid West Rhinos v Mashonaland Eagles 264/2 *",
      "title": "Mid West Rhinos v Mashonaland Eagles 264/2 *"
    },
    {
      "unique_id": "973379",
      "description": "Mountaineers 136/10  v Matabeleland Tuskers 42 *",
      "title": "Mountaineers 136/10  v Matabeleland Tuskers 42 *"
    },
    {
      "unique_id": "959221",
      "description": "Islamabad United v Quetta Gladiators",
      "title": "Islamabad United v Quetta Gladiators"
    }
  ],
  "provider": {
    "pubDate": "2016-02-23T14:01:01.467Z",
    "source": "http://www.cricinfo.com/",
    "url": "http://crm.wherrelz.com/"
  }
}
```

and I need to display title and data in my PHP website.

Comment: This is not really a question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Harry! Please see **“[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”**

Comment: Take a look to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/it/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @fusion3k don't forget [**`foreach()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus ... and also [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.echo.php), maybe... ;)

Comment: @fusion3k While where at it; `<?php` is immensely useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple :

```
$raw_json = file_get_contents('data.json');
$array = json_decode($raw_json);

foreach ($array->data AS $data) {
    echo $data->title;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $data->description;
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Where of course the file `data.json` contains your json.

Answer (score 1):

You can decode the data with `json_decode` you can find the full docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

In terms of an example piece of code, you could do something like the following:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);

if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    // Do something when you don't have valid json.
}

foreach ($decoded->data as $data) {
    echo $data->unique_id;
    echo $data->title;
}
```

`json_last_error()` will allow you to catch any invalid JSON or any other potential errors that `json_decode()` may come across, so I'd definitely reccomend using it and ensuring you have decoded valid json before doing anything with it.